# Inserted IP into MySQL database changes each time

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I have a rating script that logs users' IPs so they can't rate the file more than once.  However, every time I rate the file to test it, my $ip changes with the ip2long() function.  What's up?  Here's my code:

```
<?php

require('connect.php');

    $sheetID = $_GET["id"]; 
    $rating = $_GET["rating"];
$ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = ip2long($ip);

    $checkIPQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE sheetID = '$sheetID' and INET_NTOA(ip) = '$ip'");
    $doesIPExist = mysql_num_rows($checkIPQuery);
    if ($doesIPExist == 0) { 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO ratings (sheetID, rating, ip) VALUES ($sheetID, $rating, $ip)"); 

        echo " $ip
<script>setTimeout(function(){location.href = '../sheets.php?id=$sheetID'},1);</script>"; 
    }
    else
        echo 'You have already rated this image!'; 

?>
```

And then for the check if the user has rated script:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = ip2long($ip);

$checkIPQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE sheetID = '$id' and INET_NTOA(ip) = '$ip'");

$doesIPExist = mysql_num_rows($checkIPQuery);
```

---

Here's what I've done:

- Changed the field to an unassigned INT when the $ip wouldn't go into a varchar(15)
- I have added the ip2long() function because i changed the ip field to an INT
- I then added the INET_NTOA(ip) to read the ip2long() INT

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

**Edit:** These scripts work fine if I set the $ip to 3 for example.

Comment: are you on a system with 32-bit?

Comment: What type is the column that you're trying to put $ip into?

Comment: `INET_NTOA` returns the dotted-quad representation of the address as a binary _string_ - yet you compare it with integer (returned by `ip2long`)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just store it as a string and compare strings?

Comment: Because when it was a varchar(15) it wouldn't insert into database.

Comment: So...  you can't modify the database?

Comment: @tubaguy50035 And why should him, when ints are sufficient?

Comment: @tubaguy50035 I can in every other script on my site, but not with the rating when the ip is being inserted into a varchar.

Comment: @ruddrobinet Did you notice that you insert `$ip` into DB as it is, yet use INET_NTOA when selecting? One of these is clearly an error. )

Comment: @raina77ow As with anything, he or anyone else is more than welcome to do whatever they want.  I just don't see a point is all.  It seems like the OP is having a hard time understanding what's a string, and what's a number.  So I thought suggesting using strings all around would bring some clarity.

Comment: @raina77ow Let me see...

Comment: @ruddrobinet can you debug and show us few examples of ip/ip2long pares that you will receive?

Comment: @ruddrobinet Have you checked that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` has the same value on each request?

Comment: @raina77ow I changed it and now it sets the ip to 0 every time...

Comment: @ruddrobinet and then have you ckecked that `ip2long()` returns the same number on each request? If so, you should edit your question.

Comment: did you try to change your select query to `"... and ip = ".ip2long($ip)` as raina77ow already suggest you?

Comment: @ruddrobinet What exactly you've changed? `It` is kinda meaningless, you know.

Comment: @raina77ow  I change the insert to INET_NTOA($ip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments and a little research I found the answer and it is simple.

On 32-bit systems `ip2long()` returns negative and positive integers but `INET_NTOA()` only works with positive integers. So you have two options to fix that:

1. Change your PHP code: `$ip = sprintf('%u', ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));`
2. Change your SQL query: `... AND ip = " . ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . " ...`

You can verify this fact this way:

```
$ip  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$int = ip2long($ip);    
var_dump($ip, $int, sprintf('%u', $int));
```

This produces the following output:

```
string '192.168.1.120' (length=13)
int -1062731400
string '3232235896' (length=10)
```

Then go to MySQL:

```
mysql> SELECT '192.168.1.120', INET_NTOA(-1062731400), INET_NTOA(3232235896)
+---------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| 192.168.1.120 | INET_NTOA(-1062731400) | INET_NTOA(3232235896) |
+---------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| 192.168.1.120 | NULL                   | 192.168.1.120         |
+---------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Change which query?  The select all query or the insert query?

Comment: If you chose option #2 you must insert in your DB the result of `ip2long()` as is. Then, when you select, you must do this: `... WHERE ip = " . ip2long($ip) . " AND ...` This way you always compare the result of `ip2long()` and doesn't matter if it returns a negative or positive number.

Comment: I'm such a dunce!  I added both snippets of your code into my code, instead of just one!

Comment: This is what I get for the ip values when I use the first options:  same computer - 1st time: 184.73.195.118 2nd time: 184.73.194.246 3rd time: 184.73.184.232... They change each time...

Comment: It seems your IP is changing somehow but that is not the regular behaviour. It is not due to the code.

Comment: Put the PHP verification code I pasted above in a single file and reload it several times. Are you getting the same results?

Comment: Ok.  I mean I am testing it from my phone.  Should that make a difference?

Comment: Your mobile network provider could change your IP due to some reason.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18872/discussion-between-ruddrobinet-and-jackflash)

Comment: lolol. awesome. I gave the same answer hour earlier. I got 2 votes down and moderator remove it. And now this answer is correct...