# turn ip2long array into individual objects

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I  am using the ip2long function, which works fine and returns a long list of IP addresses within the array.

what I want to do is to put each of the ip addresses in to a mysql database, I have looked at several examples, but can not find any examples which relate to the ip2long function and if I am honest they are just confusing me.

Below is my code,

```
function ip_range($start, $end) {
$start = ip2long($start);
$end = ip2long($end);
return array_map('long2ip', range($start, $end) );
}

$range_one = "151.76.0.0";
$range_two = "151.76.255.255";
print_r( ip_range($range_one, $range_two) );
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: " returns a long list of IP addresses within the array" what?

Comment: You can just store them as va `varchar` or a `long` in your database. What problem are you running into?

Comment: I can't work out how to get the array in to the database,

Comment: How does your table look like, and what are you using PDO or MYSQLI ?

Comment: Hi I am using MYSQLI and my table has three columns id, ip and netname

Comment: @user1941709 [This is how far i came](http://pastebin.com/0rMa2VRA). You must add `ini_set('max_time_execution', 0);` and you have to fix/debug the IP values (it's always 0 for some reason).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13163238/276663

Answer (score 2):

Your function looks just fine, produces lots of ip addresses...

```
function ip_range($start, $end) {
    $start = ip2long($start);
    $end = ip2long($end);
    return array_map('long2ip', range($start, $end) );
}

$range = ip_range("151.76.0.0", "151.76.255.255");
```

But I'm still unsure about the way you want to store the ips, each in a different row or are they supposed to be in one row?

Assuming each ip in a separate row, just loop over the array:

```
foreach ($range as $ip) {
    // create db entry for $id
    // id column should be of type varchar(15)
}
```

In case just one row for a the whole ip range:

```
$ip = implode(',', $range);
// create db entry for $id
```

You should be using column type text, since these ranges can become rather long.

In both cases alot of data space is wasted, why not store the long versions of the ip range in the database?

Four columns id, ip_start as `long`, ip_end as `long`, netname; then all you have to do when querying for an ip address is to `$ip = ip2long(...)` first and then look for the network `where ip_start <= $ip and $ip <= ip_end`.